# Neo4j and spring-data: numeric index cypher queries not working?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

having some problems with cypher query and numeric indexes

```
@Indexed(unique = true, numeric = false)
private Long accountId;
```

Returns:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ start n=node:Principal(accountId = '1') return n;      
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| n                                                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[41722]{__type__:"example.package.Principal",accountId:1,name:"Simple User"} |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row
```

**But**

```
@Indexed(unique = true, numeric = true)
private Long accountId;
```

Returns:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ start n=node:Principal(accountId = '1') return n; 
+---+
| n |
+---+
+---+
0 row
```

neo4j 1.9.2
spring-data-neo4j 2.3.0.RC1

If i understand correctly this might be ralted this [discussion](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?118209-Indexed-Numeric-values-in-Cypher-queries-not-working), but it is quite old?

**UPDATE:**

If i use

```
@Indexed(unique = true, numeric = false)
```

Another interesting thing happens. Checking if relationship exists (it actualy exists in db):

count(r) is equal to 0 - incorrect:

```
Long accountId = 1L;
Map<String, Object> result = template.query(
        "START child=node:Principal(accountId='{childId}') " +
                "MATCH child-[r:IS_MEMBER_OF]->parent " +
                "RETURN count(r)", MapUtil.map("childId", accountId)).singleOrNull();
```

count(r) is equal to 1 - correct:

```
Long accountId = 1L;
Map<String, Object> result = template.query(
        "START child=node:Principal(accountId='1') " +
                "MATCH child-[r:IS_MEMBER_OF]->parent " +
                "RETURN count(r)",null).singleOrNull();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric index lookups don't work from cypher with literal values, the lucene parser doesn't  create the correct internal queries. Also with parameters, normal primitive values passed to the index are treated as strings in the neo4j lucene implementation as the query cannot know if the data was indexed numerically or as string.

```
// this won't work, you have to remove the single quotes around '{childId}'
"START child=node:Principal(accountId='{childId}') " +

    "MATCH child-[r:IS_MEMBER_OF]->parent " +
    "RETURN count(r)", MapUtil.map("childId", accountId)).singleOrNull();
```

The only way you get numeric queries to work with cypher is to pass in a `ValueContext.numeric(1)` value as parameter in a java-parameter-map to an embedded database.

Comment: One more question, do i undertad this correctly, that if i use @Indexed(unique = true, numeric = true) then i cannot execute cypher query from neo4j console/Neoeclipse?